# Nodejs Dialogflow Detect intents don't do anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

I am trying to use the `.detectIntent` method with the `@google-cloud/dialogflow` module in JavaScript.
I created an agent in dialogflow, filled up some things in the Small Talk tab. Then I went to the `console.cloud.google.com` website, added the dialogflow API to my project (the project is the same as in the dialogflow website). I have my API keys in .json like many websites and tutorials says.

My javascript code look like this:

```js
const CREDENTIALS = require('./service.js');
const PROJECTID = CREDENTIALS.project_id;
const CONFIGURATION = {
    credentials: {
        private_key: CREDENTIALS.private_key,
        client_email: CREDENTIALS.client_email
    }
};

const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient(CONFIGURATION);

async function detectIntent(languageCode = 'en-US', queryText, sessionId) {
    let sessionPath = sessionClient.projectAgentSessionPath(PROJECTID, sessionId);

    let request = {
        session: sessionPath,
        queryInput: {
            text: {
                text: queryText,
                languageCode: languageCode,
            }
        }
    };

    const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request, { maxResults: 1, maxRetries: 3 });
    console.log(responses)
    const result = responses[0].queryResult;
    console.log(result)

    return {
        response: result.fulfillmentText
    };
};
```

My `service.js` file is the JSON with the API keys and look like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "autotask-gejf",
  "private_key_id": "XXXX",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nXXXXXXX\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "autotask@autotask-gejf.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "xxxxxxxx",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/autotask%40autotask-gejf.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Every time I call the `detectIntent` function, it log nothing after the `await sessionClient.detectIntent`. I searched in the cloud console and in the dialogflow  metrics I have 100% errors...
[image: methods_error]
Can someone help me?

EDIT: I found out in the dialogflow website that it is a "Permission denied" error but I still don't know how to resolve this...
[image: permission_denied]

Comment: Since you are using API key json file of a service account, have you checked that specific service account if it has enough permissions to dialogflow?

Comment: yeah normally it should work... But I am not sure so if someone could tell me how to get all the necessary keys...

Comment: You may try and check this https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating and this https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating

Comment: Yes it is exactly what I have done...